# Running testcontainers inside a Docker container for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, testcontainers

As said in [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/inside_docker.html), if I want to run testcontainers inside a docker I have to consider the following points:

1. *The docker socket must be available via a volume mount*
2. *The 'local' source code **directory must be volume mounted at the same path inside the container** that Testcontainers runs in, so that Testcontainers is able to set up the correct volume mounts for the containers it spawns.*

How to comply with 2nd point, mainly with the `-v $PWD:$PWD` condition if I use *Docker for Windows*?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, instead socket, docker uses named pipes.

```
docker run -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine
```

But you need Windows v1709 and special version of Docker for Windows, since this feature is experimental.

More info:
https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/

As for the $PWD, on windows cmd you can use `%CD%` variable which does this same job. Powershell also has a `$pwd`, same as in linux. But unfortunatelly, they does not work with docker-compose, as they're not true environment variables.

I think easiest would be to execute a short script to create `.env` file on windows where PWD= will be set to the current dir:

```
 echo PWD=%cd% > .env
```

and you can use $PWD in docker-compose same as on linux.

Comment: But this is for Windows containers, and Testcontainers is about Linux containers.